# Array.concat.apply() different in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, firefox

Please test it in the browser's console:  Array.concat.apply(null,[[0],[1]]), its purpose is to concant the arrays to [0,1]. In Firefox I get the right answer, but in chrome it throw error like: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.

Does anyone have some clue? Is it something in ES5 or 6 just uncompleted for now, or it is just the trick invented only in firefox? I see Mozila encourage such ways in their docs.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `Array.prototype.concat.apply`? `Array` doesn't have a static `concat` method. If it works in Firefox, then they have a non-standard feature.

Comment: You could just do `[0].concat([1])` as its intended.

Comment: @MikeC, it is non-standard, its also deprecated, its part of the [generic methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods) shorthand

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks!  I finally figure out the right style: Array.prototype.concat.apply([],[[0],[1]]) , work both fine on chrome and FF.

Comment: @4castle  though I just wrote two array arguments, but the function's purpose is to concat many unknown amount arrays.

Comment: @Tivon [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) can take many parameters. Like `[0].concat([1],[2],[3])` would return `[0,1,2,3]`.

Comment: @4castle  Thanks, but in this case, I want to concat 2 dimentional arrays, like [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]] => [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MikeC and   @PatrickEvans, the proper solution is :

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([],[[0],[1]])
```

And such opinion is useful for manipulating many params.